Getting ngrok not signed after yarn updates
In the last two days, Bitdefender on my MacOS has started flagging ngrok in my Yarn caches (specifically for example, /npm-@expo-ngrok-bin-linux-arm-...)
When I codesign -[d|v] I get
-linux-arm/ngrok: code object is not signed at all

Should I be concerned? Has something changed with either Expo (or Yarn) or ngrok? I seem to be getting this whenever I update Yarn (which I need for various things, but in which I'm in no way an expert).

Can you confirm the code object wasn't signed at all as well before the update ?BitDefender flags ngrok because it is a tunneling service that can be misused for malicious activities.

@tama I'm not getting the error now so I suspect that an unsigned version was distributed with the last update and that has now been fixed. I'll see if I can confirm but I didn't take a note of the path so I'll have to dig around.
